# Where does Informatica PowerCenter look for a particular Data Transformation service if DT service name is dynamically passed to UDT?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Powercenter mapping, UDT is configured to use dynamic service name. Whenever a service name is passed as input to UDT, what location does Informatica look at for the DT service? And where is this property set?

Answer (score 0):

The Data Transformation Repository contains executable Data Transformation Services. The Repository is just a folder typically located at:

Data_Transformation_install_dir\DataTransformation\ServiceDB

You can change the default location of the Repository by opening the data transformation Configuration Editor from the start menu. From here you will expand the CM Repository Tree and click on the "File System" Option to view the base path of the repository.